# Chat client implementing my own transfer protocol

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I’m looking to build my own real time chat client and server but would like to do so without existing libraries like websockets or socket.io. Ideally I would like to be able to build my own network protocol, something like my own version of the web socket protocol with the default functionality provided by JavaScript and node.js. Does anybody have any guidance as to where to start or what options I have? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? What part of websockets is already too much? But since you're using Nodejs, the built-in [Net package](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) should pretty much cover all your needs, and it's up to you to read through it. Because right now your question's borderline [off-topic](/help/on-topic) since you're still in the "I'd like to do X" stage, instead of the "I wanted to do X, so I started on that, but I got stuck on the following code".

Comment: This is a very broad question, and so doesn't fit the format of StackOverflow. You might try to start by reading webrtc and websockets specifications and implementations to get an idea of how they work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I’m doing this for a class project that requires us to build the protocol specifications and functionality

Comment: Then please [put that fact in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Asking about how to do a homework/class assignment is fine, but are typically such artificial problems with not-real-world solutions, and anyone reading your post should be aware of that before they try to help. Although even then: make sure you've written a question that is on topic: if you've done no research, then step one is for you to do that research yourself. And then when you've found options and you tried one or more, and you get stuck with those, that's the right time to ask for help here.

Comment: If you're interfacing with browsers you have 2 real options for network protocols: SSE (which is one-way) and websockets. if you want to build something from scratch without any libraries, you'll need to start reading what these protocols look like over the write. Start reading specs and then build your own implementation.

Comment: @Evert not quite. Http long polling is still extremely popular, afaik messenger still uses it. Webrtc is another option. Upcoming webtransport is yet another option.

Comment: @freakish right, but there's no reason to use it anymore. The alternatives are widely supported and have fewer issues.